# Loopback-passport-component Allow single page application Login via Facebook

Tags: passport.js, loopbackjs

I have been using loopback-component-passport with facebook login flow. As I'm moving to a single page app, I'm doing the facebook login using the FB sdk as described here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/web

```
{
  "facebook": {
    "provider": "facebook",
    "module": "passport-facebook",
    "clientID": "<id>",
    "clientSecret": "<secret>",
    "callbackURL": "/auth/facebook/callback",
    "authPath": "/auth/facebook",
    "callbackPath": "/auth/facebook/callback",
    "successRedirect": "/auth/account",
    "failureRedirect": "/login",
    "scope": [
      "email"
    ],
    "failureFlash": true
  }
}
```

I'm able to retrieve the FB access token with the FB sdk, and sending the `response.authResponse.accessToken` value to `GET http://localhost:3000/auth/facebook/callback?access_token=<token from FB sdk response>` but I get an html response.

Am I doing something wrong or loopback does not support this feature?

Answer (score 0):

For that use case, where you get the access token on the client, I think the [passport-facebook-token](https://www.npmjs.com/package/passport-facebook-token) module works better.

I've just been dealing with facebook oAuth, and I found that the best solution. You avoid the oAuth redirections, while still taking advantage of passport for the token validation and permanent session handling.